# Excel VBA - my findnext in my selcted range is not working

Tags: excel, vba

hello if there is any who can help with this issue

I have a range of groups 1 to many (up to 12 rows - one row after an other per group) the initial part of the string as repeated I do not know how time they are repeated but ever time they are I need extract the relevant data which is everything after the repeated string. Now not all 12 row are in the group sometimes there are 11 or less but they are no blank rows in the group of data so what I do is once I find my header row I call a subroutine to go through the block of data and do my extraction, but when I get back and use the .findnext(v) it will not go to the next header

```
    With big_rng      ' this is column A selected
        Set v = .Find("Submarket:", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not v Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Row
            Do
                Call this1(need, c.Row, tech, daily_date)
                Set v = .FindNext(v)
                need = need + 1
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With
```

When I call this1 what I am doing is selecting another range because I do not know if my data is in the correct order I use another selection

```
    Cells(i, 1).Select ' I know which row my group starts and I select down

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    ' check for substrings and copy across if the substring exists e.g.

    With Selection

    Set d = .Find("Degradation =", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

            If Not d Is Nothing Then
                spos = InStrRev(Cells(d.Row, 1), "=")

                If Mid(Cells(d.Row, 1), spos + 1, 1) = " " Then
                    output_sht.Cells(n, 5) = Right(Cells(d.Row, 1), Len(Cells(d.Row, 1)) - (spos + 1))
                Else
                    output_sht.Cells(n, 5) = Right(Cells(d.Row, 1), Len(Cells(d.Row, 1)) - spos)
                End If

            Else
                output_sht.Cells(n, 5) = "Error in Data"
            End If
```

when this Sub end my original selection is gone (it was column A:A), and my .findnext(v) gives me the last row of the previous group not the first row of the next group if one exists

how do I loop via findnext whilst keeping my original selection in tact

Thank you in advance

Robert

Comment: Excel uses the last `FIND` values when using `FINDNEXT`, so it's using the values in the `this1` search.  I think you'll have replace `.FINDNEXT` with another `FIND` using the last found item as its starting point, but keep the firstAddress so it knows when it gets back to the start.

Answer (score 0):

I had a play around and came up with this code.
Row 1 must be above the search range (i.e. the headers), so the data is in addresses A2:A10 and B2:B10.
I placed `Submarket:` in `A2`, `A4`, `A5` & `A7` and `Sumarket1:` in `B3`, `B4`, `B5` & `B7`.

The output was (on individual lines):

> **big - $A$2** sml - $B$3 sml - $B$4 sml - $B$5 sml - $B$7 **big - $A$4** sml
>   - $B$3 sml - $B$4 sml - $B$5 sml - $B$7 **big - $A$5** sml - $B$3 sml - $B$4 sml - $B$5 sml - $B$7 **big - $A$7** sml - $B$3 sml - $B$4 sml - $B$5
>   sml - $B$7

```
Sub test2()
    Dim big_rng As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim foundrow As Long

    Set big_rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")
    With big_rng
        Set v = .Find("Submarket:", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not v Is Nothing Then
            Do
                foundrow = v.Row
                Debug.Print "big - " & v.Address
                this1
                'Resize the search range to ignore rows already searched.
                With big_rng.Resize(big_rng.Rows.Count - foundrow + 1).Offset(foundrow - 1)
                    Set v = .Find("Submarket:", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                End With
            Loop While Not v Is Nothing And v.Row <> foundrow
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Sub this1()

    Dim sml_rng As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim firstAddress As String

    Set sml_rng = Sheet1.Range("B1:B10")

    With sml_rng
        Set v = .Find("Submarket1:", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not v Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = v.Address
            Do
                Debug.Print "sml - " & v.Address
                Set v = .FindNext(v)
            Loop While Not v Is Nothing And v.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```